# Select an element without a specified ID

Tags: jquery, selector

got a row of elements:

```
<div class="container" id="box1">
<div class="container" id="box2">
<div class="container" id="box3">
```

how to select all of them without box2 ?
thought this would solve the problem,

```
var i =  "#box2";
$('.container:not(i)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$('.container:not(i)');
```

should be

```
$('.container:not(' + i + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working. See http://jsfiddle.net/bmDDD/

Are you sure your dom is loaded when you execute that javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".container").not("#box2")
```

should work according to http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 0):

This `$('.container:not(#box2)');` works fine

**Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Pqa/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DOM is fully loaded using `$(function() { ... }`

This works fine:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".container[id!='box2']");
    });
<script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yhr3w/2/)**